# android setting up the Action bar items

Tags: android

The below layout not displaying search icon only the another icon is displaying and the search comes as the drop down menu of other icon.I want it as separate icon in the action bar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.diveintojava1.MainActivity" >


<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="search"
      android:icon="@drawable/search1"
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
       />

  <item android:id="@+id/file"
      android:title="drop"
      android:icon="@drawable/moremenu" >

    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
              android:title="java" />
        <item android:id="@+id/open"
              android:title="rate us" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

And below is the java code of implementing menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, see more here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and here http://sourceoncloud.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/actionbar-compact/

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:appcompact="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.diveintojava1.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="search"
          android:icon="@drawable/search1"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          appcompact:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
           />

      <item android:id="@+id/file"
          android:title="drop"
          android:icon="@drawable/moremenu" >

        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                  android:title="java" />
            <item android:id="@+id/open"
                  android:title="rate us" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" Change ifRoom to always

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
```

into this:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```